# Empty Image Mouse Click

Tags: c#, wpf, image, mouseclick-event

I am placing an Image in a Grid layout in C# with WPF. I want to have a mouse click event for it, but if the Image source is not set then the event is never fired. Is there a way to change that? I want the event to fire regardless of if the Image source is set or not.

```
<Image Focusable="True" IsEnabled="True" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"
MouseLeftButtonDown="Image_MouseLeftButtonDown" MouseDown="Image_MouseDown" Stretch="Fill" />
```

The mouse events are never fired unless the property Source is set.

Comment: what do you mean by "the Image source is not set"

Comment: Like an image is not loaded to the control.

Comment: can u show me a part of your code so i can help you

Answer (score 1):

Place you `Image` inside a `Grid` and register the events on the Grid

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1" Background="White" Grid.Column="0" MouseLeftButtonDown="Image_MouseLeftButtonDown" MouseDown="Image_MouseDown">
  <Image Focusable="True" IsEnabled="True" Stretch="Fill" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: That doesn't work either. No click events work for an Image control unless the image is set.

Comment: @Emrys90 okay you are right, you need at least set a background color on the Grid

Answer (score 0):

```
 <Grid>
 <Image Height="150" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="218,18,0,0" Name="image1"   Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" Source="path" MouseLeftButtonDown="image1_MouseLeftButtonDown" />
 </Grid>
```

Comment: That did not work for me either. I gave up on trying to do it by this method. Instead I am just getting mouse coordinates and dividing by row height and column width.

Comment: i advise you to don't use it because sometimes the mouse using image will not be detected so if you want to use it i advise you to use a rectangle with the image that have the same properties

Answer (score 0):

```
<Grid>
    <Image Height="150" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="218,18,0,0" Name="image1" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" Source="/WpfApplication1;component/Images/2012-12-14-1535%20%281%29.jpg" MouseLeftButtonDown="image1_MouseLeftButtonDown" />
    <Rectangle Height="150" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="218,18,0,0" Name="rectangle1" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" />
 </Grid>
```