# Drag and Drop works on TextBlock Control but not on Image Control

Tags: wpf, image, drag-and-drop

Google has finally failed me. I have looked everywhere I can think of but to no avail. In my project I have an image control I would like to drop pictures onto and have their filepath saved in a variable and the image displayed in the control.

After several attempts to make it work I decided to open a new project and simplify everything. Right now it seems to boil down to the Drop Event not firing on the Image Control while it does fire on a TextBlock Control.

Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:VB"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" AllowDrop="True" Drop="TextBlock_Drop"/>
    <Image AllowDrop="True" Drop="Image_Drop"/>
</Grid>
```

Code Behind:

```
Class MainWindow

    Private Sub TextBlock_Drop(sender As Object, e As DragEventArgs)

        MessageBox.Show("fired")

    End Sub

    Private Sub Image_Drop(sender As Object, e As DragEventArgs)

        MessageBox.Show("fired")

    End Sub

End Class
```

Doesn't matter the file type. Every file dropped on the TextBlock results in the MessageBox opening. Every file dropped on the Image Control does absolutely nothing.

I have no clue why and any suggestions would be appreciated!

EDIT: Thanks to suggestions from Bulutay Saraç in his comments below I found that adding a stock Image file to the project and referencing it as the source for the Image control fixed the issue and the event now fires properly. For those who do not wish to add a default image file see Bulutay Saraç's answer below for a simple and effective work around.

Comment: Is your image empty?Because if image doesn't have a source its mouseDown, Drop events don't work.It behaves like a transparent object.

Comment: So I should have an empty BitmapImage variable setup as a property in the main window and then make that the Image Control's Source?

Comment: If you don't set image source, events won't work.You need to use a container like Grid and put your image control into it then set the BackGround property of Grid to Transparent at the end call the events from Grid.This is the clearest way.

Similar problem : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15525120/empty-image-mouse-click

Comment: I added a detailed answer below that contains codes.

Comment: Thanks! That's a big help

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a way to solve this problem.Put your image control into a container (I used Grid) give your container a transparent background and call your events on container.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" AllowDrop="True" Drop="TextBlock_Drop"/>
    <Grid AllowDrop="True" Drop="Image_Drop" Background="Transparent">
        <Image />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

**VB**

```
Class MainWindow
    Private Sub Image_Drop(sender As Object, e As DragEventArgs)
        MessageBox.Show("Image")
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBlock_Drop(sender As Object, e As DragEventArgs)
        MessageBox.Show("Text Block")
    End Sub
End Class
```